# C \ UNIX \ strcmp first use is wrong, correct all other times

Tags: c, unix, strcmp

hey all i wrote some code on microsoft VS which is suppose to compare passwords entered to ones stored in database and return approved or denied...
it worked perfectly good on windows, but after converting to UNIX (using eclipse) a funny thing happend - always, the first call to this function doesnt return the approved value when it should, but calling for the function again with exactly the same params returns approved... as desired.
after debugging i am pretty sure the problem is in the "strcmp", that returns false on the first run and true in all other runs on the exact same parameters.

anyone has an idea on what could be the problem??

an example for a commands:
add jt    111
// adding the password to the DB

login jt 111

> > denied

login jt 111

> > approved

```
void login_helper(char *user, char *password){
        int found = 0;
        int i;
        for (i=0 ; i<space ; i++){
            if (strcasecmp(data[i].name,user) == 0) {
                found = 1;
                if (strcmp(data[i].hash ,Md5FromString(password)) == 0)
                    {
                    printf("approved.\n");
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    printf("denied.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (found == 0) printf("denied.\n");
    }
```

Comment: Post the code or it didn't happen. :)

Comment: @Matteo Italia He posted the code, he just didn't format it, and because the `<` is stuck on `space` in the for loop, Markdown treated that as (invalid) HTML.

Comment: @yuval, did you consider the problem might be from your Md5FromString function?

Comment: @zneak: yep, typical, I forgot to check. :S

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to diagnose the problem, but I am pretty sure `strcmp()` will always have the same return value given the same parameters. I suggest you check that the strings being passed are what you think they are and are correctly null-terminated.

Comment: "adding the password to the DB", eh? Do you have some race-condition here, where you are trying to retrieve the password from "the DB" before it has stored it for retrieval?

Comment: @yuval Please would you also post the code that calls login_helper? I'd like to see where the user and password char* arguments are initialised.

Comment: I think your problem is with the global variable `data`. How is `data` set? Why do you have global variables (`data` and `space`) at all? ???

Answer (score 3):

I predict that the call to `Md5FromString(password)` returns a pointer to a buffer that's no longer valid when the `Md5FromString()` function returns. That would mean that you're running into undefined behavior, and getting lucky in some cases and unlucky in others.

Post the code to `Md5FromString()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd really doubt there's any problem in strcmp(). :-)

(There's an excellent book on SW development called "The Pragmatic Programmer", by Andrew Hunt and David Thomas, which has a tip regarding debugging called "'select' is not broken", which ultimately means that it's really unlikely that a basic system function (e.g. select() or strcmp()) is broken.)

Did you try printf'ing the contents of 'data[i].hash' and the value returned by 'Md5FromString(password)' right before strcmp()?

Something like:

```
            char *md5;
            ...
            md5 = Md5FromString(password);
            printf("i: %d, hash: %s, md5: %s\n", i, data[i].hash, md5);
            if (strcmp(data[i].hash, md5) == 0)
                {
                ...
```

Also, who allocates memory for function Md5FromString()? Can you send the code for Md5FromString()?

Cheers,
Paulo